# Java - Change one element in the grid presentation

Tags: java

The code I have now prints out a grid made from an array:

```
//some code that generates the array gameCards[] = {'a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'}
//n is the size/length of the array 
public String BoardToString(){

    int gridCount = 1;
    int cardCount = 0;
    char[][] showBoard = new char[n/4][4];
    while (cardCount < n){
        for(int row = 0; row < (n/4); row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < 4; column++){
                showBoard[row][column] = gameCards[cardCount]; // also how can I use gameCards if it's generated in another method within the same class?
                System.out.print("X (" + gridCount + ") ");
                gridCount++;
                cardCount++;
            }
            if ((n/4) > 1) System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It will print out something like this:

```
// if n = 8
X(1) X(2) X(3) X(4)
X(5) X(6) X(7) X(8)
```

The presentation of the grid corresponds to the order of the elements in the original array. If I want to achieve something like this:

```
a(1) X(2) X(3) X(4)
X(5) X(6) X(7) X(8)
```

or

```
a(1) X(2) X(3) X(4)
X(5) b(6) X(7) X(8)
```

How should I write the loop so it can print out most of the masked grid and only showing 1 actual element (maximum element I need to reveal is 2)?

Comment: When and where do you want to print an 'a' or a 'b', what is the condition to do so? Also, your BoardToString() doesn't return a String as stated in its signature.

Comment: This is actually for a card game Pairs. Players can flip any card they want, and the board should reveal the card they just flipped. If two card matches, they should remain revealed; if there is a mismatch, they will be flipped back (only show X's) again. I made my array char, should I change it to Strings then?

Comment: To draw an 'a' or a 'b' for a card that a player picks, the BoardToString() method needs to be aware of the card that's selected in the form of a (x, y) position in the showBoard.

Comment: It's off-topic, but you don't have to use `cardCount` variable. You can use `row` and `column` instead, so your code would look like: `showBoard[row][column] = gameCards[4*row + column];` And there is no need for `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to store coordinates of the card user picked. Then when printing a card check if it is the card user picked. If it is, print its letter instead of an X. Remember first choice and repeat the process for the second card. After second round clear the two cards you stored and repeat.

```
for(int column = 0; column < 4; column++){
    showBoard[row][column] = gameCards[cardCount]; // also how can I use gameCards if it's generated in another method within the same class?
    if (pickedRow1 == row && pickedCol1 == column || pickedRow2 == row && pickedCol2 == column) {
        System.out.print(CARD_LETTER + " (" + gridCount + ") ");
    } else {        
        System.out.print("X (" + gridCount + ") ");
    }
    gridCount++;
    cardCount++;
}
```

For your second question. When you generate `gameCards` in the other method, either pass it to `BoardToString` as a parameter or you can store it to the [instance variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and later access it in the `BoardToString` method.